# Display XML with stylesheet in JEditorPane

Tags: java, xml, swing, xslt, jeditorpane

I have an XML file, which uses an XSS and XSL stored in the folder to display the XML in a proper format. 
when i use the following code

```
JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
editor.setBounds(114, 65, 262, 186);
frame.getContentPane().add(editor);
editor.setContentType( "html" );
File file=new File("c:/r/testResult.xml");
editor.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
```

All i can see is the text part of the XML without any styling. what should i do to make this display with style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The `JEditorPane` does not automatically process XSLT style-sheets.  You must perform the transformation yourself:

```
    try (InputStream xslt = getClass().getResourceAsStream("StyleSheet.xslt");
            InputStream xml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Document.xml")) {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(xml);

        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(output));

        String html = output.toString();

        // JEditorPane doesn't like the META tag...
        html = html.replace("<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">", "");
        editor.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        editor.setText(html);
    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | TransformerException e) {
        editor.setText("Unable to format document due to:\n\t" + e);
    }
    editor.setCaretPosition(0);
```

Use an appropriate `InputStream` or `StreamSource` for your particular `xslt` and `xml` documents.